# why does react.js when upload file return cors

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

```html
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("CustomerName", this.state.customerName);
    formData.append("Email", this.state.email);
    formData.append("Phone", this.state.phone);
    formData.append("PageNumber", this.state.pagesNumber);
    formData.append("Notes", this.state.notes);
    formData.append("WritingConversionTypeId", this.state.writingConversionTypeId);
    formData.append("WritingDocumentTypeId", this.state.writingDocumentTypeId);
    formData.append("WritingTimePeriodId", this.state.writingTimePeriodId);
    formData.append("files", 'null');
    
     writingRequest.postwritingRequest(formData).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

**when attach to headrs form data it return CORS**
i'm using react.js and server side ASP.NET Core3.1...
and it works when  removing the (Content-Type: multipart/form-data) from headers
it works in swagger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loShg.png)

in

```js
at React Service to Call Api

import http from "../../config/http";
import endPoints from "../endPoints";

const writingRequestUrl = endPoints.WRITING_REQUEST_ENDPOINT;

export default {
  postwritingRequest(writingRequest) {
    return http
      .post(
        writingRequestUrl,
        writingRequest
          , {
          headers: {
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      });
  },
};
```

```js
In StartUp
At ASP.NET CORE
ConfigureServices

//Enable CROS To allow access to the resource
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            }));

 

In Configure

app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

Comment: Hi! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. 
Please, read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

CORS has nothing to do with react, your browser prevents the call as the client runs on a different domain than your server. On production this is usually not an issue, since both are typically running on the same domain.

If you want to avoid CORS in development, the **Create React App** bundle comes with a proxy server, that appends the CORS header to all HTTP requests, as described in the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/).

Simply add the URL to your api to your `package.json` like so:

```
"proxy": "www.url-to-your-api.com"
```

Then make sure to run all requests from your react app against absolute links, so instead of calling `www.url-to-your-api.com/api/` you should simply use `/api/`, this will use the proxy in development and the regular route in production.